# QTCreator won't find headers for QTVTK Widget?

Tags: qt, linker, qt-creator, qmake, vtk

Hello I added a `Qtvtk widget` in QtCreator to my window and then tried to build and run the program, I then received a error saying that some headers were missing.

I would like to emphasize that I didn't add any of my own code yet, I just dragged and dropped from the toolkit the widget.

Now maybe I'm not thinking this correctly but if the item appears in the toolkit and is doped without a problem, the headers should be accessible or else it wouldn't have appeared in the toolkit.

I'd like to mention I'm working on Ubuntu, I haven't installed `VTK` on it's own but with the `PCL` package, a library which uses VTK for it's visualizer,so there maybe something funny with my library installation orders.

The headers which can't be found:

```
#include "vtkSystemIncludes.h"
#include "vtkABI.h"
```

The error itself, yes it's win32 and I'm on linux, is:

```
/usr/include/QVTKWin32Header.h:23: error: vtkSystemIncludes.h: No such file or directory
```

So if there is something more to be done so I can use the widget please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you Properly Compiled and linked the Library to the Project? Have you also linked the Source files to the Project?

include the source by adding  "INCLUDEPATH += path_to_source*" to your .pro file 
e.g INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../src    for a source located in the directory up the present working directory with name src

and library by adding "LIBS += -L path_to_compiled_library" to your .profile

If already done and Not working, Double check to ensure that the path is correct..

Comment: If you would be so kind as to say exactly what the path to library is for QtVTK widget(On Ubuntu) I will add it, that is the basis of my problem if the widget appeared in my toolkit I didn't expect the need to add the includes by hand. Tell me the path to the qtvtk lib (or at least it's name) and I will implement this.

Comment: I honestly have not used QtVtk before, my advice was based on the error message. However, a little research reveals this: There Should be a vtk-x.x directory in /usr/include/vtk-x.x or /usr/lib/include/vtk-x.x . I want to point out that the steps to use Qtvtk may not be as simple as drag and drop. Pleas go though this links and try to extract relevant information, try to ensure that your system is atleast properly setup: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Tutorials/QtSetup and http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx#Qt . Below is an example .pro file I found

Comment: Sample Pro file I found: QT       += opengl
LIBS    += -L/usr/lib/vtk-5.6 -lvtkCommon -lvtksys -lQVTK -lvtkQtChart  -lvtkViews -lvtkWidgets -lvtkInfovis -lvtkRendering -lvtkGraphics  -lvtkImaging -lvtkIO -lvtkFiltering -lvtklibxml2 -lvtkDICOMParser  -lvtkpng -lvtkpng -lvtktiff -lvtkzlib -lvtkjpeg -lvtkalglib -lvtkexpat  -lvtkverdict -lvtkmetaio -lvtkNetCDF -lvtksqlite -lvtkexoIIc -lvtkftgl  
-lvtkfreetype -lvtkHybrid
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/lib/include/vtk-5.6
----- This may also Help http://www.qtforum.org/article/18473/tutorial-for-using-qt-with-vtk.html  .Best of Luck